# How can I return objects instead of objects inside an array when reading from json files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, parsing

I'm reading some json files from a directory and serving them as an endpoint. I have the below code:

```
 fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, filesPath) {
            if (err) throw err;
            filesPath = filesPath.map(function(filePath){ 
                return dirPath + filePath;
            });
            async.map(filesPath, function(filePath, cb){ 
                fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', cb);
            }, function(err, results) {
                res.send(results);
            });
        });
```

This returning something like this:

```
[         
  {
    "Country1":{
       "countryTEST":"US",
       "FindLocale":{
          "Test":{
             "Test":false,
             "Test":""
          },
          "Test":{
             "Test":false,
             "Test":"value"
          }
       },
        "payment":[
          "CREDIT_CARD",
          "NOT_CREDIT"
       ],
       "test":"1234",
       "phoneNumb":[
          ""
       ]
    },

    "Country2":{
       "countryTEST":"US",
       "FindLocale":{
          "Test":{
             "Test":false,
             "Test":""
          },
          "Test":{
             "Test":false,
             "Test":"value"
          }
       },
        "payment":[
          "CREDIT_CARD",
          "NOT_CREDIT"
       ],
       "test":"1234"
       "phoneNumb":[
          ""
       ]
    }
  }
]
```

However, I want the returned response to just look like this (without the array wrapping the objects)

```
 {
    "Country1":{
       "countryTEST":"US",
       "FindLocale":{
          "Test":{
             "Test":false,
             "Test":""
          },
          "Test":{
             "Test":false,
             "Test":"value"
          }
       },
        "payment":[
          "CREDIT_CARD",
          "NOT_CREDIT"
       ],
       "test":"1234"
       "phoneNumb":[
          ""
       ]
    },

    "Country2":{
       "countryTEST":"US",
       "FindLocale":{
          "Test":{
             "Test":false,
             "Test":""
          },
          "Test":{
             "Test":false,
             "Test":"value"
          }
       },
        "payment":[
          "CREDIT_CARD",
          "NOT_CREDIT"
       ],
       "test":"1234"
       "phoneNumb":[
          ""
       ]
    }
  }
```

I have tried doing something like `res.send(JSON.stringify(results));` and `res.send(JSON.parse(results));` . But this didn't for work me to get my desired output.

Please kindly suggest how I can get the output I need. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: `res.send(results[0]);` works for you?

Comment: @RahulBhobe I have tried res.send(results[0]); but it will return only the first object, for example, country1, but I would want all the objects to be returned, country1....country200

Comment: See if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63734096/11057988) works for you. I have assumed your inputs to be what you say your inputs are. But in your original post, they seem to be different.

Comment: grab the first element from your array `arr[0]`

Comment: @RahulBhobe I'm very very sorry if the sample example I provided turned out to be too simple. Your code definitely passes the sample example I provided. However, my JSON actually looks more like that (I have edited the description)

Comment: @RahulBhobe So I have multiple objects that have the same structure as the Country1 object that I put as a sample. sorry for any confusion

Comment: Could you provide 2 entries in the sample input and output instead of one?

Comment: @RahulBhobe Very much appreciate your help. I have updated the description with 2 entries.

Comment: You seem to be missing couple of `,` which makes the input and output invalid. You also have duplicate keys in the nested objects. But fixing those things, I see that my code works as per your required output.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an array to object:

```js
let arr = [
    { "country1": { "capital": "some capital", "currency": "$" } },
    { "country2": { "capital": "some capital", "currency": "$" } }
];
let obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
You need the first element of that array and to be parsed.

```
res.send(JSON.parse(results[0]));
```

Comment: This solution won't work in my case since I'm trying to return all the objects NOT only the first item.

Comment: Then your requirement doesn't make much sense.
What do you mean by all objects without array wrapping? @mmm20

Comment: To make it clear, please post the example that the above solution doesn't work with.